# How do I write this update query?

Tags: sql-server

I am running this query on a table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_type as pdt_typ, skill  
FROM [dbo].[Call_Data] 
WHERE skill NOT LIKE '%HUA%'
AND product_type IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY skill ASC
```

This returns the following records:

```
pdt_typ     skill
HUA         1004
HUA         1007
HUA         1010
HUA         1020
C3_Sandbox  1020
HUA         1024
HUA         1025
HUA         1026
HUA         1028
HUA         1029
HUA_Oxford  1031
HUA         1031
C3_Sandbox  1031
HUA         1038
HUA_Oxford  1038
C3_Sandbox  1038
HUA         1039
HUA         1040
HUA         1043
HUA         1046
C3_Sandbox  1048
HUA         1048
```

If I remove the `AND product_type IS NULL` from the `WHERE` clause, the results would be like:

```
pdt_typ     skill
HUA         1004
NULL        1004
HUA         1007
HUA         1010
HUA         1020
C3_Sandbox  1020
NULL        1020
HUA         1024
HUA         1025
HUA         1026
NULL        2016
HUA         1028
HUA         1029
HUA_Oxford  1031
HUA         1031
C3_Sandbox  1031
NULL        1031
HUA         1038
HUA_Oxford  1038
C3_Sandbox  1038
NULL        1038
HUA         1039
HUA         1040
HUA         1043
HUA         1046
C3_Sandbox  1048
HUA         1048
NULL        1048
```

I need to update the above table. For example:`

```
UPDATE [dbo].{Call_Data] 
SET product_type = (
    SELECT product_type 
    FROM [dbo].[Call_Data]
    WHERE product_type IS NOT NULL 
    AND skill = 1004) 
WHERE product_type IS NULL
-- AND skill = 1004. use skills that have one product_type (not including the NULL product_type) but 
-- do not use skill = 1020, 1031, 1038 or 1048 because those skill IDs have 2 or more product_types 
-- (not including the NULL product_type).
```

I need help with this part.  How do I only select the skills with a single product_type and update the NULL product_type with that skill's product_type. Example:

```
    pdt_typ     skill
    HUA         1004
    NULL        1004
```

`Should now become:

```
pdt_typ     skill
    HUA        1004
    HUA        1004
```

SQL Server 2016.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to correlate the subquery, and use `HAVING` to limit the result

```sql
UPDATE c1
SET product_type = c2.product_type
FROM [dbo].[Call_Data] c1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT product_type 
    FROM [dbo].[Call_Data] c2
    WHERE c2.product_type IS NOT NULL
        AND c2.skill = c1.skill
    GROUP BY product_type
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) c2
WHERE product_type IS NULL
```